# Python explicit webdriverwait, attributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'browser'

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am having a problem when trying to use explicit webdriverwait in python with selenium:

```
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 30)
    element = wait.until(EC.browser.find_element_by_xpath(h2))
finally:
    try:
        infouno = browser.find_element_by_xpath(h2).text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print "Nothing found"
        infouno = 'n/a'
    try:
        infotwo = browser.find_element_by_xpath(i2).text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print "Nothing found 2"
        infotwo = 'n/a'
        time.sleep(3)
```

Browser is defined as as firefox, ad the xpath path (h2) is defined and is being pulled from a spreadsheet.

We are currently getting the below error:

```
Nothing found
Nothing found 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\pythonscript.py", line 109, in (module)
element = wait.until(EC.browser.find_element_by_xpath(h2))
attributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'browser'
```

Anyone have any ideas what has gone wrong here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the code

```
element = wait.until(EC.browser.find_element_by_xpath(h2))
```

with:

```
element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, h2)))
```

and try.. Also, check this link for properly using waits: http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html